# Are there any corpora of informal and unstructured text labelled for Named Entity Recognition?

Tags: corpora, german, named-entity-recognition, annotated-data, catalan

I have been searching since last week for annotated informal texts (with a lot of misspelled words, slang, etc.) to test some Named Entity Recognition tools for research purposes. For example, it would be interesting to find informal texts with labels for people's names, mentions of people, names of places, telephone numbers, etc.

I am searching mainly for these languages: German and Catalan.

I have found data from the [GermEval Task](https://sites.google.com/site/germeval2014ner/data) but it is not exactly what I need because the corpora are from news and Wikipedia. Concerning Catalan, I have found zero data.

I am searching also for other languages such as English and Spanish but I have found something that seems interesting enough for me for the moment and I will happily share with you:

- [CS Workshop dataset English-Spanish](https://code-switching.github.io/2018/#shared-task-id)
- [W-NUT Ner dataset](https://noisy-text.github.io/2017/emerging-rare-entities.html)

Comment: Wait, are you *the* Jurafsky? :O

Comment: @WavesWashSands Who knows!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For German language, there is the corpus [NoSta-D](https://vlo.clarin.eu/record?q=nosta-d&docId=http_58__47__47_hdl.handle.net_47_11022_47_0000-0000-1D83-C) containing non standard varieties of German including a chat corpus. It is hosted by the CLARIN-D centre at Tübingen.